# Strange "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when refactoring fields (processing.run()) in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, refactor

I wrote a small function to refactor fields (just one field really) in a given Shapefile which I output as a temporary layer. In principle it works just fine. I build a String with all the info the algorithm needs and when I input the String as a whole it works perfectly fine. However, when I hand over the String as variable I get a strange error (strange at least for me).

Here's my function:

```
def refactorFieldShp(self, sourceLayer, field_name):
        """
        Funktion zum Refactorn eines Feldes in einem Shapefile, hier: Vergrößern der Länge eines Textfelds
        based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302114/refactor-fields-using-pyqgis3
        """
        procString = "{'FIELDS_MAPPING':["
        fields_Shp = sourceLayer.fields()
        for field_Shp in fields_Shp:
            length = str(field_Shp.length())
            if field_name.casefold() == field_Shp.name().casefold() or field_name.casefold() == field_Shp.alias().casefold(): length = "254"
            procString += "{'expression': '\"" + field_Shp.name() + "\"','length': " + length + ",'name': '" + field_Shp.name() + "','precision': " + str(field_Shp.precision()) + ",'sub_type': 0,'type': " + str(field_Shp.type()) + ",'type_name': '" + field_Shp.typeName() + "'},"
        procString = procString[:-1] + "], 'INPUT':'" + sourceLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri() + "', 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}"
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("procString: " + procString, level=Qgis.Info)
        #copied from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412691/adding-temporary-output-of-processing-algorithm-to-the-map-canvas-using-pyqgis
        processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:refactorfields",procString)
        output = 'tbd'
        return output
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/Sickboy/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\writeout_xplan_columns\writeout_xplan_columns_algorithm.py", line 378, in processAlgorithm
last_index = self.setupColumnValues(sourceLayer, field_alias, last_index, sourceLayerDB, owComplex)
File "C:\Users/Sickboy/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\writeout_xplan_columns\writeout_xplan_columns_algorithm.py", line 291, in setupColumnValues
self.refactorFieldShp(sourceLayer,field_name)
File "C:\Users/Sickboy/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\writeout_xplan_columns\writeout_xplan_columns_algorithm.py", line 160, in refactorFieldShp
processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:refactorfields",procString)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~2.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 144, in runAndLoadResults
p = parameters[param.name()]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However if I copy the output of *procString* from console into the function like this:

```
def refactorFieldShp(self, sourceLayer, field_name):
        """
        Funktion zum Refactorn eines Feld in einem Shapefile, hier: Vergrößern der Länge eines Textfelds
        based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302114/refactor-fields-using-pyqgis3
        """
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("field_name an refactorFieldShp() übergeben: " + field_name, level=Qgis.Info)
        procString = "{'FIELDS_MAPPING':["
        fields_Shp = sourceLayer.fields()
        for field_Shp in fields_Shp:
            length = str(field_Shp.length())
            if field_name.casefold() == field_Shp.name().casefold() or field_name.casefold() == field_Shp.alias().casefold(): length = "254"
            procString += "{'expression': '\"" + field_Shp.name() + "\"','length': " + length + ",'name': '" + field_Shp.name() + "','precision': " + str(field_Shp.precision()) + ",'sub_type': 0,'type': " + str(field_Shp.type()) + ",'type_name': '" + field_Shp.typeName() + "'},"
        procString = procString[:-1] + "], 'INPUT':'" + sourceLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri() + "', 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}"
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("procString: " + procString, level=Qgis.Info)
        #copied from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412691/adding-temporary-output-of-processing-algorithm-to-the-map-canvas-using-pyqgis
        #processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:refactorfields",{'FIELDS_MAPPING':[{'expression': '"gml_id"','length': 80,'name': 'gml_id','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"uuid"','length': 80,'name': 'uuid','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"text"','length': 80,'name': 'text','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"rechtsstan"','length': 80,'name': 'rechtsstan','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"gesetzlich"','length': 80,'name': 'gesetzlich','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"gliederung"','length': 80,'name': 'gliederung','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"gliederu_1"','length': 80,'name': 'gliederu_1','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"ebene"','length': 10,'name': 'ebene','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 4,'type_name': 'Integer64'},{'expression': '"hatgenerat"','length': 80,'name': 'hatgenerat','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"hoehenanga"','length': 80,'name': 'hoehenanga','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"user_id"','length': 10,'name': 'user_id','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 4,'type_name': 'Integer64'},{'expression': '"created_at"','length': 10,'name': 'created_at','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 14,'type_name': 'Date'},{'expression': '"updated_at"','length': 10,'name': 'updated_at','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 14,'type_name': 'Date'},{'expression': '"konvertier"','length': 10,'name': 'konvertier','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 4,'type_name': 'Integer64'},{'expression': '"refbegruen"','length': 80,'name': 'refbegruen','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"gehoertzub"','length': 80,'name': 'gehoertzub','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"wirddarges"','length': 80,'name': 'wirddarges','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"externeref"','length': 254,'name': 'externeref','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"startbedin"','length': 80,'name': 'startbedin','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"endebeding"','length': 80,'name': 'endebeding','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"rechtschar"','length': 80,'name': 'rechtschar','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"wirdausgeg"','length': 80,'name': 'wirdausgeg','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"wirdausg_1"','length': 80,'name': 'wirdausg_1','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"wirdausg_2"','length': 80,'name': 'wirdausg_2','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"wirdausg_3"','length': 80,'name': 'wirdausg_3','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"wirdausg_4"','length': 80,'name': 'wirdausg_4','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"reftextinh"','length': 80,'name': 'reftextinh','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"flaechensc"','length': 1,'name': 'flaechensc','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 2,'type_name': 'Integer'},{'expression': '"reflandsch"','length': 80,'name': 'reflandsch','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"ziel"','length': 80,'name': 'ziel','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"massnahme"','length': 80,'name': 'massnahme','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"refmassnah"','length': 80,'name': 'refmassnah','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"sonstziel"','length': 80,'name': 'sonstziel','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'},{'expression': '"inverszu_w"','length': 80,'name': 'inverszu_w','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'String'}], 'INPUT':'Z:/Christian/Arbeit/GDI-Service/xmi2db_2021/QGIS Forms/Testdaten/xplan_standard_shapes_befuellt/bp_ausgleichsflaeche.shp', 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
        output = 'tbd'
        return output
```

... it works fine. And no, I didn't change anything, I just copy pasted the console output and overwrote *procString* in the function call with it.

Any ideas what's wrong here or how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Algorithm parameters should be a dictionary object not a string object. When you pass your `procString` variable, you are giving the parameters argument as a string which is incorrect. My guess is that when you copy and paste from the console it is being parsed correctly as a dictionary (without the enclosing double quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben, after sleeping over it I came to the same conclusion but thanks so much for your hint anyway :-)

I really don't like Python dictionaries (esp. in conunction with arrays) but in case someone ever needs a function to refactor fields here it is:

```
def refactorFieldShp(self, sourceLayer, field_name):
    fieldsMapping = []
    fields_Shp = sourceLayer.fields()
    i = 0
    for field_Shp in fields_Shp:
        if field_name.casefold() == field_Shp.name().casefold() or field_name.casefold() == field_Shp.alias().casefold(): length = 254
        fieldsMapping.append({'expression': field_Shp.name(),'length': length,'name': field_Shp.name(),'precision': field_Shp.precision(),'sub_type': 0,'type': field_Shp.type(),'type_name': field_Shp.typeName()})
        i += 1
    procDict = {'FIELDS_MAPPING':fieldsMapping, 'INPUT': sourceLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri(), 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
    processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:refactorfields",procDict)
    output = 'tbd'
    return output
```

(This function just copies all existing fields and leaves them as they are. It only changes the length of one field passed to the function as **field_name**.)